# Name for "bicontinuous function" that's not bijective?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We know that an invertible continuous function whose inverse is also continuous is called a homeomorphism. But is there a name for a not-necessarily-bijective function that is "bicontinuous" in the sense that it sends open sets to open sets and the preimage of open sets are open sets?

Comment: An open continuous function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is an [open (continuous) map](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps).  Usually continuity is assumed, and the word is suppressed from notation.

Answer (score 4):

A function with the first property is called **open** (or an **open mapping**) and the second is just continuity, so I would call this an **open continuous function**.